# "plotGoogleMaps enable to start device png" error

Tags: r, plotgooglemaps

When plotting as spatialDataFrame with a factor as the first column and many levels you get the error "plotGoogleMaps enable to start device png".

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it is trying to plot all the levels and the legend gets tooooo long. You should try to use a more meaningful column for the legend.

I created a fork that fixes this and other issues (some values in the data.frame could prevent plotGoogleMaps from plotting) : https://bitbucket.org/cmbce/plotgooglemaps. It is easy to install with devtools.